# Can't start firewall or automatic updates in Windows XP

Tags: windows-xp, firewall, shared-access

On a friends laptop following some viruses infestations there is a problem in starting the Windows firewall. The error is:

> Could not start the Windows
>   Firewall/Internet Connection
>   Sharing(ICS) service on Local
>   Computer.
>
> Error 2: The system cannot find the
>   file specified

When attempting to turn on automatic updates in the security centre, the message is:

> We're sorry. The Security Center could
>   not change your Automatic Updates
>   settings. To try changing these
>   settings yourself, go to System in
>   Control Panel. On the Automtic Updates
>   tab, select Automatic (recommended),
>   and then click OK.

All the options under "Automatic Updates" are greyed out.

I've tried the suggestions below and many others:

http://windowsxp.mvps.org/sharedaccess.htm

http://support.Microsoft.com/kb/892199

http://windowsxp.mvps.org/repairwmi.htm

I can't do a repair install because the installer doesn't detect existing versions. It's XP pro service pack 3.

Answer (score 0):

I would scan your computer first for malware -> [MalwareBytes](http://www.malwarebytes.org)

If that comes up clean attempt to start both the services in safe mode to confirm the files arnt currupt.

Repair Windows Firewall [here](http://forum.oscr.arizona.edu/showthread.php?t=2284)

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion, I already ran a full scan a couple of times.

Comment: Do they start ok in safe mode?

Comment: Same problem in safe mode

Comment: try my added link

Comment: Thanks for the link. However the suggestions in that thread are largely the same as those in the links I already tried. In addition all the Firewall Administrative templates are set to "Not Configured"

Answer (score 0):

After cleaning up a virus I found that it set various services to disabled, Automatic Updates being one of them. If you right click on My Computer, click Manage, open the Services section on the right you'll get a list of services. Find the ones mentioned, double click on them and change the startup preference to Automatic, then start them.

If they were disable with just a setting, that should handle it. If they are disabled because of missing or corrupt files, you might try manually downloading and reinstalling Service Pack 3 and the Windows Update installer. They can both be found on Microsoft's download site.